# Using Trace32 with Qualcomm FFA

Tags: debugging, brew-framework, jtag, brewmp, trace32

Does anyone knows of any resources regarding the debugging of BREW and/or BMP applications on Qualcomm FFA using Lauterbach JTAG/Trace32 (e.g. .cmm scripts, instructions etc.)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What in particular are you interested in? Debugging using TRACE32 is an extensive subject :)

In general, since BREW/BMP applications are dynamically loaded, their symbols are not loaded automatically by Trace32. To have symbols you need to break at a point when your app was loaded, and load symbols at the address your app is loaded.

There are some scripts that were written internally to automate that process in BREW 4 and BMP--have you tried the [regular support channels](https://brewmobileplatform.qualcomm.com/devnet/forum.jsp) to inquire if those are provided and supported for BREW developers?

In BREW 3.x, please take a look at [this presentation on BREW Application debugging from 2007](http://www.brewconference.com/brew_2007/pdf/Prog-805_Fryckman_v01.pdf) - it has a wealth of useful information.

Also, which BREW/BMP version? Which FFA? and other minor details that could help others help you :)